# Why can't java recognize this Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote this Regular Expression:

`((http):\/\/\S*\.(jpg|gif|png))`

This Regex should find every image link in a string

And as you can see it work fine if you click the link below.

http://rubular.com/r/FYwP8Aprdb

But when I then paste it into java and escape all of the back- slashes and call replaceAll(regex, string);

The program can't find anything?

```
String regex = "((http):\\/\\/\\S*\\.(jpg|gif|png))";
boxText.replaceAll(regex, "**$0**");
```

The code above should get every image in a string and then capsulate it in **$0** But upon running the program and testing, nothing happens.

```
public class SSCCE {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String boxText = "http://www.desibucket.com/db2/01/26039/26039.jpg";

    String regex = "((http):\\/\\/\\S*\\.(jpg|gif|png))";
    boxText.replaceAll(regex, "**$1**");        

    System.out.println(boxText);
}

/* output

  http://www.desibucket.com/db2/01/26039/26039.jpg

 */

}
```

My assumption is that I've escaped the regex incorrectly, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output produced by this expression?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are *immutable*: The expression is matching but the value is never re-assigned to the result of `replaceAll`

```
boxText = boxText.replaceAll(regex, "**$1**");
```

Comment: @ShaunWild Are you sure youre looking at the output from the updated code (rebuild, etc.)?

Comment: That's so perculiar, I paste in your code next to mine and they're the exact same, but yours works and mine doesn't... I'll just use yours.. :S thanks!